# How can I use a Django model's verbose_name in a field definition?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
# models.py
#==============================================================================
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):

    ...

    exists = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name = 'The Foo still exists.',
        default = True
    )

    ...
```

What I would like to do is use the model's `verbose_name` in place of 'Foo', so that my model would look something like this:

```
# models.py
#==============================================================================
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):

    ...

    exists = models.BooleanField(
        verbose_name = f'The {self._meta.verbose_name} still exists.',
        default = True
    )

    ...
```

Obviously, this doesn't work as written since `self` doesn't exist in that context. I tried the following, which seemed to work:

```
# models.py
#==============================================================================
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):

    ...

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().init(*args,**kwargs)

        self.exists = models.BooleanField(
            verbose_name = f'The {self._meta.verbose_name} still exists.',
            default = True
        )

    ...
```

However, when I tried `Foo.save()` I ended up with `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Invalid field name(s) for model Foo: 'exists'`. Ultimately, I intend to make `Foo` into an abstract model for other models to inherit (which is *not* the question here, just some added context).

The question is, how can I use the model's `verbose_name` in the field definition?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: No, I haven't figured it out yet. I'm working around it by hard coding, for the time being, but it's not a very DRY solution...